# Why is access token in query string parameters for OAuth2.0?

Tags: security, authentication, oauth-2.0

I am relatively new to OAuth, and I wonder why the access-token is passed around in query string parameters in OAuth2.0, given that this may get saved in browser history as plain text.

I understand that the query string parameters are transported over SSL and cannot be possibly intercepted. But, once they are in browser cache/history, aren't they plain text, and accessible to other programs?

If so, why is OAuth2.0 defined this insecure way?

Comment: Can you pls. show a link to any reference that says you have to use query parameters for the token. Use the [edit] link below the question to add further information to your question.

Comment: I couldn't find any documentation that says access-token is placed in query params. But this service that i am testing right now sends me response code of 302 and has a location set to my callback uri, with a bunch of query params including access-token. Could it be that this service is implementing it incorrectly? I don't want to tell the name as it is potentially disastrous for them from a security standpoint.

Comment: OAuth2 [recommends](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-7) to use the `Authorization` header. So I think it's more a problem of that service. Ask the service provider. IMHO your question is not valid because it makes a false assumption.

Comment: Got it. I appreciate your comments, and partially agree with you on validity of the question. By the way, I came across this https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-bearer-23.xml#query-param which mentions delivery of access-token using query parameters. So albeit less secure, this remain a possibility I guess? Also, wouldn't this make the question useful for someone else?

Comment: I'm not an OAuth2.0 expert, but I see you linked to a draft from 2012. In the rfc I linked above I didn't find it. Genereally I think the question is off topic here, and might better fit on [Information Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/).